# SELECT record in object

Tags: c#

I am looking similar like Select record in dataset

```
foreach (DataRow r in Histryds.Tables[0].Select("Cust_ID='" + custid + "'"))
```

Below is for object, how to use .Select?

```
foreach (History hr in rows)
```

Comment: you can use LINQ to select data for object list type. You cannot use the same way like DataTable

Comment: Probably you need to use `AsEnumerable` like this: `foreach (History hr in (rows.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Cust_ID == custid)))`?

Comment: only have GetEnumerator...

Answer (score 0):

you need a where. Not Select

```
foreach (DataRow r in Histryds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Where(t=>t["Cust_ID"]==customerId))
{
   //do the needfull
}
```